# Simple insert not working from form?

Tags: php, sql

This won't work for me, I have been using inserts and every other sql statment there on this work, but for some reason this is not working.

The table below is structured as follows.

```
**passenger_journey**
j_id  user_id
142    1
142    14
```

Below all I'm trying to do is insert the logged in users id which is the $user_id and the journey id which is $id. Thee are working are the variables are set.

I think a possible problem may be the $id as I'm getting this from the url using the GET method.

```
<?php

    $insert_passenger = "INSERT INTO `passenger_journey` VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) ."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($user_id) . "')";



        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

        mysql_query($insert_passenger);

        }
    ?>


<form method="POST">
<br/>Add yourself to this journey!<br/> 
<input type ="submit" value="Sign up for this Journey"/>
</form>
```

This has been driving me mad for hours any help would be great.

Comment: Where do the values come from? Are you sure db connection is established properly?

Comment: `echo $insert_passenger;` is it what you expect? does it work in the likes of phpmyadmin or the mysql consol?

Comment: Which are the data types of the columns? If they are numeric, you have to remove the '

Comment: So what's not working?

Comment: Hey guys thanks, The insert is just not working, the data types are both INT. Both the variables are set. The value $id comes for the url by using the GET, I echo both and they are working. The database connect is working and is required.

Comment: @kiks73 quotes for integers are allowed, just not required unlike for strings

Comment: @TrevorKeating: Please, for the love of all that is holy (and all that is not, too) [***don't use the `mysql_*` extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)*** It's been **deprecated** for some time now

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't match up:

```
<form method="POST">
    <br/>Add yourself to this journey!<br/> 
    <input type ="submit" value="Sign up for this Journey"/>
</form>
```

And:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    mysql_query($insert_passenger);
}
```

You need to assign a name to your submit button for that if statement to be true:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up for this Journey"/>
```

...and you'll need to pass those variables into the action of your form to be able to use them in the $_GET superglobal.

```
<?php
$your_id = // define your id here, I assume in your insert query this should just be null.
$user_id = // define your user id here however you're getting it... sessions...?
?>
<form method="POST" action="?id=<?=$your_id?>&user_id=<?=$user_id?>">
```

**NOTE:** if your `id` and `user_id` variables are coming from sessions, cookies etc or anything that can be retrieved in the script doing the insert, **definitely** do it there instead of passing it through an HTML form when you don't need to.

Usually when inserting data with MySQL, the relevant `id` column will be set to `auto_increment`, and you either wouldn't pass in a value for it or you'd pass in null so you let it assign its own value. You should probably be doing that here (although I don't know your situation at all):

```
$insert_passenger = "INSERT INTO `passenger_journey` VALUES (null,'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['user_id']) . "')";
```

**Side note:** Not only is the fact that `mysql*` is deprecated going to cause you trouble, but this script is vulnerable to SQL injection and XSS.

> Docs/more info:

- http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php
- http://www.sitepoint.com/php-security-cross-site-scripting-attacks-xss/

Comment: Thanks for the advice, the row doesn't need to be auto increment as I' not using it for a unique purpose.

Comment: It was just the submit button name, you were right! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @TrevorKeating cool, but you should address your security vulnerability issues before you move on.